# Android Room [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database when using Relation and Junction

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

this is my first question here.

I'm building an app using Room database and I tried following [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/database-relations-with-room-544ab95e4542) tutorial because I need to implement a many-to-many relation.

However I keep getting the following error as soon as I try to build the app:

**error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: OwnerDogCrossRef)
private final java.util.List dogs= null;**

My entities, with the cross reference data class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "owner_table")
data class Owner(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "owner_id")
    val id: String,

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "owner_name", index = true)
    val name: String,
    // some other columns

@Entity(tableName = "dog_table")
data class Dog(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "dog_name")
    val name: String
    // some other columns

@Entity(primaryKeys = ["owner_name", "dog_name"])//, "move_learned_by"])
data class OwnerDogCrossRef(
    val owner_name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val dog_name: String
    // some other columns
```

My junction data class:

```
data class OwnerWithDogs(
    @Embedded val owner: Owner,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "owner_name",
        entityColumn = "dog_name",
        associateBy = Junction(OwnerDogCrossRef::class)
    )
    val dogs: List<Dog>
)
```

My DAO:

```
@Dao
inteface OwnerDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM owner_table WHERE owner_name = :name")
    fun getOwnerWithDogs(name: String): LiveData<List<OwnerWithDogs>>
}
```

I also added the OwnerDogCrossRef to my database as below:

```
@Database(
    entities = [Owner::class, Dog::class, OwnerDogCrossRef::class],
    version = 2,
    exportSchema = false
)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class MainDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    //some logic
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 10):

Go to your **Database.kt** file and make sure the cross-reference table has been included in the list of entities there. Yours may differ to the example below, but I hope you can see what you may have missed.

```
@Database(entities = [Owner::class, Dog::class, OwnerDogCrossRef::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

...

}
```

This is because the *Owner*, *Dog*, and *OwnerDogCrossRef* are all tables that the database needs to know about, whereas *OwnerWithDogs* is merely going to join the relevant tables in a transaction, as multiple queries will be run, as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships). See also [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Database) for the database documentation showing how to include the entities for a particular database.

Comment: And if the primary keys for `Owner` and `Dog` are NOT string, you should annotate `OwnerDogCrossRef` properties with `@PrimaryKey` instead of defining them in `@Entity` annotation

Answer (score 0):

```
data class OwnerWithDogs(
    @Embedded val owner: Owner,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "owner_name",
        entity = Dog.class,
        entityColumn = "dog_name",
        associateBy = @Junction(
        value=OwnerDogCrossRef.class,
        parentColumn = "owner_name",//variable name in your OwnerDogCrossRef
        entityColumn = "dog_name")
    )
    val dogs: List<Dog>
)
```

Try this code.
For further ideas ,try this link
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Junction

Comment: I just tried your approach but it gives me the same error